# Multiple submit keys for a single topic in the Hedera Consensus Service

Tags: hedera-hashgraph

When creating a new Topic with Hedera Consensus Service, is there a way to have more than one or multiple submitted for a single Topic?

Answer (score 2):

I run through a number of key signing scenarios in my H18 talk.  You can mix and match these strategies to model varying business scenarios including this one.

https://youtu.be/OI7oT9Knnlc?t=1038

Answer (score 0):

Yes. All transactions support key lists, thresholds, and nested key structures.

Docs for Keys: https://docs.hedera.com/guides/core-concepts/keys-and-signatures

So on your topicCreate you'd have a type of threshold key.
Create topic doc: https://docs.hedera.com/guides/docs/sdks/consensus/create-a-topic

Note that if you specify a list, all private keys corresponding to the public keys have to sign.

If you specify a threshold key, only the required number has to sign.
You could for example set up a 1 of 5 threshold meaning any of the 5 can sign, or a 2 of 5 meaning a minimum of 2 of the 5 have to sign